# Difference in seconds between user input and current date

Tags: bash, shell, date, datetime

I need difference between two dates in seconds. I input datetime in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" and then calculate difference in seconds, but the `run_time` is in UTC timezone and `current_time` is calculated from system timezone.

```
#!/bin/bash
run_time=$1
run_time=$(date -d "$run_time" +"%s")
current_time="$(date +"%s")"

echo $run_time
echo $current_time
echo "$(($run_time-$current_time))"
```

How to retrieve absolute value of seconds between current datetime and another one?

Edit: actually that script has worked after restart of computer. No clue why previously it showed up different results. I have not changed anything in settings, nor computer time.

Comment: `date -u` if `-u` is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right @[Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel), based on your comment a sample script could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
STARTTIME_UTC=$1
STARTTIME_UTC=$(date -u -d "${STARTTIME_UTC}" +"%s")

echo "CURRENT DATE: $(date)"
CURRENTTIME="$(date +"%s")"

echo
echo "STARTTIME_UTC: ${STARTTIME_UTC} sec since"
echo "CURRENTIME: ${CURRENTTIME} sec since"
echo

echo "RUNTIME: $((${CURRENTTIME}-${STARTTIME_UTC})) sec"
```

As per original question

> I input datetime in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"

the value of input time seconds in `${STARTTIME_UTC}` will be set to zero (`:00`) whereby the value of current time seconds in `${CURRENTIME}` will be set to what the clock provides. I.e., if it is 18 seconds before the next minute and the runtime would be almost zero, the script will report a difference of 42 seconds.

Comment: Result of your script. I have no idea why after restart of computer it shows different result.
`sh new.sh "2020-04-29 22:40"
CURRENT DATE: Wed, 29 Apr 2020, 22:51:45 CST

STARTTIME_UTC: 1588200000 sec since
CURRENTIME: 1588171905 sec since

RUNTIME: -28095 sec`